# Diagonalizing sparse unitary matrix

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I have to gather the eigenvalues of a sparse unitary matrix.
Basically there is just an element different from zero in each
row and column (it's the transfer matrix of some Markovian process).

My question here is how to proceed, what would be the best choice
among all the suite of functions. I have seen that eigs could help,
but I also saw that one has to choose the *inital vector*.

Comment: Does the matrix have a single non-zero entry in each column and row? in this case it is a permutation matrix times a dilation matrix and the eigenvalues are simple to calculate (complex unit vectors according to permutation cycles times appropriate ratios from the dilation factors)

Comment: Yes, in fact in a limit it's just a typical permutation matrix. How do you know this factorization? Are they still easy to calculate if there are degeneracies (many eigenvalues equal to zero) and/or the dimension of the vector space scales as N^2?

Answer (score 2):

The following code eventually defines `pdeig` which returns the eigenvalues of a matrix which is a `pdmatrix` i.e. a product of a permutation and diagonal matrix, or in other words a matrix like the question describes. Calculating the eigenvectors quickly is also possible (they have an explicit formula):

```
issquare(m) = all(x->x==size(m,1),size(m))
isunique(v) = v == unique(v)
permmatrix(sigma) = 
  [i==sigma[j] ? 1.0 : 0.0 for i=1:length(sigma),j=1:length(sigma)]
mat2perm(m) = [findfirst(m[:,i]) for i=1:size(m,1)]

function ispdmatrix(m)      # used to verify input matrix form
  (r,c,v) = findnz(m)
  return issquare(m) && isunique(r) && isunique(c)
end

function pdfact(m::Matrix)  # factor into permutation/dilation
  ispdmatrix(m) || error("input matrix must be a PD matrix")
  n = size(m,1)
  p = mat2perm(m)
  d = [p[i]>0 ? m[p[i],i] : zero(eltype(m)) for i=1:n]
  return (p,d)
end

# return eigenvalues from factored pdmatrix
function pdeig(p::Vector{Int},d::Vector)
  n = length(p)
  active = trues(n)
  eigv = Vector{Complex{eltype(d)}}(0)
  for i=1:n
    if !active[i]
      continue
    end
    if p[i]>0
      j=1
      cump = d[i]
      k=p[i]
      active[i]=false
      while active[k] > 0
        j+=1
        cump *= d[k]
        active[k] = false
        k=p[k]
      end
      append!(eigv,[cump^(1.0/j)*exp(2*im*π*m/j) for m=1:j])
    else
      push!(eigv,0.0 + 0.0im)
    end
  end
  return eigv
end

pdeig(m::Matrix) = pdeig(pdfact(m)...)

n = 4   # testing vector to matrix transformation of permutations
σ=randperm(n)
@assert mat2perm(permmatrix(σ))==σ
```

For example, the following:

```
m = [ 0.0 1.0 0.0 ; 2.0 0.0 0.0 ; 0.0 0.0 0.0 ]
pdeig(m)
```

Outputs:

```
    3-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
 -1.41421+1.73191e-16im 
  1.41421-3.46382e-16im 
              0.0+0.0im
```

Since these matrices are diagonalizable, the eigenvalues should provide the diagonal matrix (just use `diagm` on them).

These matrices are very structured, and a proper Julia treatment would define a type for these matrices and then define the various linear algebra functions to dispatch on this type.

In case of errors, just add a comment, and I will try to fix them (or if I happen to see a nice refactoring then I'll edit).

BTW the calculations introduce small numerical errors, these should not be a problem and can be eliminated with proper rounding (so no need to get scared of `-1.0` being `-1.0+1.234234e-16im`)

Comment: Thank you so much. Now question, I suppose this is a theorem, where can I see for the proof of it?

Comment: Minimal googling did not find a theorem for permutation+dilation, but for just permutation matrices, there is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970702/what-are-the-properties-of-eigenvalues-of-permutation-matrices and this explains the bulk of the complexity (for which the cycle structure of the permutation is calculated in `pdeig`).... maybe this should be made into a new theorem (or lemma).

Comment: final question, is this your definition of dilation?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)

Comment: and googling for permutation+scaling given the following paper which details the theory justifying the calculation: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379594904138